# multiple balls in a box with collision detection

Tags: python, vector-graphics

**What the problem is**

I have to simulate balls in a box of 1 by 1.
i have to give the ball a random speed and a random angle it takes off in. 
however when i plot the balls they go straight and have an asymptote at 0.25.
i double cheked my math but i cant find the problem?

**My code**

```
   import numpy
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   import math
   import random



def rand_tuples(aantalballen):  # here i make a function that randomly makes a list with lists in #

    list_balls = []             # the list, every index is a ball with x_pos , y_pos , speed , rotation #

    for i in range(aantalballen):

        list_balls.append([0.25, 0.75,0.1* random.random(), 2* math.pi*random.random()])


    return list_balls 


def ball_step(list_balls, dt): # this function calculates the steps the balls takes #


    x = list_balls[0]   
    y = list_balls[1]
    vx = math.cos(list_balls[3]) * list_balls[2]    # speed in the x direction #
    vy = math.sin(list_balls[3]) * list_balls[2]    # speed in the y direction #
    dt = dt

    x_pos = x + (vx * dt)            # calculates the actual positions #
    y_pos = y + (vy * dt)

    if x_pos <= 0 or x_pos >= 1:     # collision detection #
        vx = -vx


    if y_pos <= 0 or y_pos >= 1:
        vy = -vy



    return x_pos, y_pos, vx , vy     # returns the new positions but the same speed so that they can be used again#


def move_ball(ballen, tijd, dt):  # takes a list of balls, time they move and the time steps they take# 

    positions_balls = { }     # hold my position in  {0:{'x':[positions}, 'y':{...}}}

    time_1 = 0

    for i in range(len(ballen)) :  

        positions_balls[i] = None    # make a key with empty value #
        time_1 = 0

        cordinates = {'x':[], 'y':[]}       # make the dictionary where my values go into #

        while time_1 < tijd:    

            bal = ball_step(ballen[i] , dt)    # call bal step to calculate my x and y position #
            ballen[i] = bal
            cordinates['x'].append(bal[0])      
            cordinates['y'].append(bal[1])
            time_1 += dt



            if int(time_1) == tijd:
                positions_balls[i] = cordinates # finally add the dictionary to my main dictionary #

    print positions_balls
    return positions_balls






dic = move_ball(rand_tuples(30), 3, 0.01)

plt.plot(dic[0]['x'], dic[0]['y'])
plt.show()
```

i do not have enough reputation to post a picture of the plot :(

Comment: `list_balls[n]` is a tuple, not a single value.

Comment: I am new to programming did i over comment?

Comment: i changed it to a list, still the same problem

Comment: You need to add some `print` statements to your code for your own debugging. For instance, add `print x` after the line `x = list_balls[0]`. I suspect `x` is not what you expect it to be...

Answer (score 0):

ball_step() takes in (I think; comments are your friend) x, y, speed, rotation. It outputs x, y, speed x, speed y. That's assigned back to the original list.